# How to initialize writable computed properties of radio-buttons

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vuejs3` with `options api`
as shown in the code posted below, i have two `<input>` and i do binding via `v-model`.

when i run the app, the logs statements of the `get()` of the computed properties, initially returns `undefined`, hence, initially, none of the radio-buttons were selected.
my question is, what is the optimal way to set initial value to `vModelTimeSeriesAgo` and `vModelEpochAgo`, ans how please?

**template.html**:

```
<template>
    <cds-radio-group name="interaction" layout="vertical" cds-layout="p-y:lg"> -->
        <cds-radio>
            <label>{{ tempTextTimeSeriesAgo }}</label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                :value="vModelTimeSeriesAgo"
                @input="$emit('update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo', $event.target.value)"
                @change="onTimeSeriesAgoChanged()"/>
        </cds-radio>

        <cds-radio>
            <label>{{ tempTextEpochAgo }}</label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                :value="vModelEpochAgo"
                @input="$emit('update:vModelEpochAgo', $event.target.value)"
                @change="onEpochAgoChanged()"/>
        </cds-radio>
    </cds-radio-group>
</template>



export default {
name: 'NDVIComparisonGUI',
    date() {
        return {};
    },
    components: {},
    props: {},
    emits: ['update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo', 'update:vModelEpochAgo'],
    computed: {
        vModelTimeSeriesAgo: {
            get() {
                console.log('get.vModelTimeSeriesAgo:', this.vModelTimeSeriesAgo);
                return this.vModelTimeSeriesAgo;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('set.vModelTimeSeriesAgo:', value);
                this.$emit('update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo', value);
            },
        },
        vModelEpochAgo: {
            get() {
                console.log('get.vModelEpochAgo:', this.vModelEpochAgo);
                return this.vModelEpochAgo;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('set.vModelEpochAgo:', this.vModelEpochAgo);
                this.$emit('update:vModelEpochAgo', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onTimeSeriesAgoChanged() {
            console.log('onTimeSeriesAgoChanged');
        },
        onEpochAgoChanged() {
            console.log('onEpochAgoChanged');
        },
    },
};
```